# Vector question regarding plane and area

Tags: calculus

How do i find the area enclosed within the $3$ points when the plane intersects the $x, y$ and $z$ axis and

The plane is $ax+by+cz=1$

Need help on solving this as it has been bothering me for some time

Answer (score 4):

Find the points where the plane intersects the $x$, $y$, and $z$ axis. Then find the distances between these three points and use [Heron's formula](http://www.mathopenref.com/heronsformula.html) to find the area of the trianlge defined by them.

Answer (score 2):

The points are $X=(\frac 1a,0,0), Y=(0,\frac 1b,0), Z=(0,0,\frac 1c)$

You can either compute the lengths of the sides of the triangle using pythagoras, and then the area using [Heron's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula). Or compute the magnitude of the vector product $(Y-X)\times (Z-X)$ which may be computationally simpler.

Comment: The cross product is definitely simpler and I think I get the form $\cfrac 1{abc}\cdot\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}$. Note this is homogeneous (unaffected by scaling everything) and symmetrical, as expected.

Comment: how do i find the points?

Comment: @grenn Well the point on the $x-axis$ is defined by the equations $y=0, z=0$ (that's what the axis is) so that $ax=1$ and $x=\frac 1a$ hence point $X$ - others similarly.

Comment: Just to confirm - by my calculations Pythagoras and Heron gives the same answer, but with more work.

Comment: And I didn't mean homogeneous - I meant scaled quadratically as an area should be.